# Extract type using boolean field and conditional type from constant

Tags: typescript

I have a constant that I'm trying to extract a type from:

```
const PERMISSIONS = {
   viewer: {
     category: 'View',
     label: 'View Access Only',
     deprecated: true
   },
   full_user: {
     category: 'Edit',
     label: 'Full Access',
     deprecated: false
   },
   admin: {
     category: 'Edit',
     label: 'Admin Access',
     deprecated: false
   }

} as const;
```

I am able to extract a category|label string type using this:

```
type RoleToPermissionsMap = typeof PERMISSIONS
type keys = keyof RoleToPermissionsMap;
type values = RoleToPermissionsMap[keys];
type categories = `${values['category']}`;
type labels = `${values['label']}`;
type magickeys = `${categories}|${labels}` 
// 'View|View Access Only' | 'View|Full Access' | 'View|Admin Access' | 'Edit|View Access Only' | 'Edit|Full Access' | 'Edit|Admin Access';
type filteredMagicKeys = ? // Not sure how to filter out 'deprecated: false'
```

My desired type filters out based on the `deprecated` flag. So in this example it would only have the `'Edit|*'` strings.

I believe everything I'm looking for is available at compile time, so I should be able to express this type, but I don't know how to filter the constant based on the `deprecated` flag.

Comment: You are missing a comma and a `}`, are those typos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When extracting the value, add in an `Exclude` so that if `{ deprecated: true }` is assignable, the object gets excluded from the union.

```
type RoleToPermissionsMap = typeof PERMISSIONS;
type values = Exclude<RoleToPermissionsMap[keyof RoleToPermissionsMap], { deprecated: true }>;
type filteredMagicKeys = `${values['category']}|${values['label']}`;
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes a ton of sense and works for the values. Is it possible to extend this solution to also get the filtered keys which have those values?